# Hide table columns for mobile view

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have 5 rows (i may change it to 4 or 6) but 4 fixed columns totally, in that I want to hide the 3rd column in the mobile view, tried adding the below CSS but nothing works perfectly.

@media (max-width:768px){.tablepress :nth-child(4n+2) { display: none !important; }}

Comment: can u post code of table... as I can get now ..why (4n + 2) use (3n + 0) th child.

Comment: why 4n+2 ?? it should be `:nth-child(3)`

Comment: If I add :nth-child(3) only the 1st row is visible, rest of the rows are hidden.

Comment: Here is the screenshot -https://snag.gy/fkqBYa.jpg

I will add many rows but only 4 columns, So can someone give me the correct CSS which I want to display all the rows by hiding the 3rd column

Comment: @AbbasNabilou Any help?

Comment: @UchitKumar any help?

Comment: from your comment, it seems that ..html structure is different .. so if u could share atlease som part of code

Comment: @UchitKumar here it is

<tr class="row-1">
<th class="column-1">A</th>
<th class="column-2">B</th>
<th class="column-3">C</th>
<th class="column-4">D</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="row-hover">
<tr class="row-2">
<td class="column-1">1</td>
<td class="column-2">2</td>
<td class="column-3">3</td>
<td class="column-4">4</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-3">
<td class="column-1">1</td>
<td class="column-2">2</td>
<td class="column-3">3</td>
<td class="column-4">4</td>
</tr>

Comment: according to above code your column has class. so try `@media (max-width:768px){.column-4:display: none})`

Answer (score 1):

use correct css selector ..

```
tbody tr td:nth-child(3) { display : none}
```

for table header similarly use

```
thead tr th:nth-child(3) { display : none}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the content in the 3 column is hidden but the table header remains the same , Please check the screenshot-> https://snag.gy/vM7FYr.jpg

Comment: @media only screen and (max-width: 768px){tbody tr td:nth-child(3) { display : none}}

@ media only screen and (max-width: 768px){thead tr td:nth-child(3){ display : none}}

added this code, but still, the header is same as 4 columns and body content is 3

Comment: @Ram96 use updated answer .. basically after thead tr th:nth-child(3)